# Como que criar um link dinâmico para uma tela do django admin?

Tags: django, jinja2

Como usar as `tags` dos templates do django para criar um link dinâmico para os paineis de administração?

Digamos que o nome do painel admin seja `ProductsAdmin`, e que essa tabela foi criada e registrada no app `store`. E está disponível na seguinte url: `/admin/store/products/`

Eu gostaria de saber como que faço para gerar um link dinâmico para essa tela, para assim evitar colocar um link *hardcoded* no template.

Eu tentei dessa maneira e não funcionou:

```html
<a href="{% url 'admin:store:products' %}">
    Confira os produtos disponíveis
</a>
```

e a seguinte mensagem de erro foi exibida:

`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'store' is not a registered namespace inside 'admin'`

Comment: Esse namespace não esta vinculado o urlspatterns a mensagem informa que não encontrou nas rotas "urls.py" ..  path('suaRota/',  algumaview.asview(), name="algum_name_definido").. mostre como esta suas todas para  ver como podera melhorar o resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Quando é registrado uma classe que herda da classe django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin o django registra as views associadas com o seguinte padrão:

- Dashboard com a lista: `admin:<APP_NAME>_<CLASS_NAME>_changelist`
- Formulário para criação: `admin:<APP_NAME>_<CLASS_NAME>_add`

Dessa forma, para criar um link para a página descrita na pergunta seria da seguinte maneira:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:store_products_changelist' %}"> Link </a>
```

Comment: Só pra acrescentar, se quiser usar o model pra pegar estes dados e tornar isso um pouco mais "dinâmico" poderia usar [`Products._meta.app_label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#app-label) e `Products._meta.model_name`. para preencher `APP_NAME` e `CLASS_NAME` respectivamente.